# Java HashSet not using Comparator of custom object

Tags: java

Before someone asks, I've already read through the responses under this similar posting ([.Contains() method not calling Overridden equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318909/contains-method-not-calling-overridden-equals-method)) and was still unable to fix my issue;

I created a custom object called `Tuple`. Here it is:

```
    class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
         public int x = -1;
         public int y = -1;
         public int val = -1;
    
         public Tuple(int x, int y, int val) {
             this.x = x;
             this.y = y;
             this.val = val;
         }
    
         @Override
         public boolean equals(Object o) {
             if (o instanceof Tuple) {
                 Tuple o2 = (Tuple) o;
                 if(this.x == o2.x && this.y == o2.y) {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         }
    
         @Override
         public int compareTo(Tuple t) {
             if(this.val < t.val) {
                 return -1;
             } else if(this.val > t.val) {
                 return 1;
             } else {
                 return 0;
             }
         }
    
         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "(" + x + "," + y + "," + val + ")";
         }
     }
```

I created a `HashSet` and added objects to it, checking for equality:

```
HashSet<Tuple> set = new HashSet<Tuple>();
Tuple t1 = new Tuple(2, 1, 10);
Tuple t2 = new Tuple(2, 1, 10);
test1.add(t1);
System.out.println(test1.contains(t1));
System.out.println(test1.contains(t2));
System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
System.out.println(t2.equals(t1));
System.out.println(t1.equals(t1));
System.out.println(t2.equals(t2));
```

This is the output:

```
true
false
true
true
true
true
```

I am expecting `test1.contains(t2)` to produce `true` since `t1` and `t2` are equal. As you can see, I made sure to check both reflexivity and symmetry for `equals`.

Comment: You need to override hashCode() as well.

Comment: Where do you add `t2` to the `Set`? And yes, it's best to override `hashCode` too

Comment: @g00se The point is that I don't, but since `t1` and `t2` are equivalent I should be able to use them interchangeably. But yes, I was able to resolve this by overriding `hashcode`

Comment: Yes I see now that that's what you meant.